# Laravel how to make top menu display only in one row

Tags: css, laravel-5

I develop under Laravel 5.4. There is a top menu show as in the picture 1. [top menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd6c7.png)
 However, I want to the menu show like picture 2 [ideal top menu show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGOMh.png),show in any size screen only in one row. Is there any good solution to make it? Like by change the menu font auto?

```css
.venus-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #dedede;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="venus-menu" id="top_bar">
      <li><a href="#" title="首页" target="_blank">首页</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title1" target="_blank">title1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title2" target="_blank">title2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title3" target="_blank">title3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title4" target="_blank">title4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title5" target="_blank">title5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title6" target="_blank">title6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title7" target="_blank">title7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title8" target="_blank">title8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title9" target="_blank">title9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="title10" target="_blank">title10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post the complete css of the navigation which you write you wrote only `venus-menu` class properties.

Comment: It might be not possible to show a menu with 11 menu items to show only in one row on all the size screen resolutions. Possible option would be to replace the text menu items into icons to save more space

Answer (score 0):

Check working fiddle to get the same, but you have to change css part

**NOTE** -  As you mansion that "top menu display only in one row"

Working fiddle

**[fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/49/)**

```css
.navbar-minimalize {
  margin:5px 50px 5px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #dedede;
}
.content ul.venus-menu {
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.content ul.venus-menu li {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.content ul.venus-menu li a {
  display:block;
  padding:10px 15px;
  font-size:15px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#505050;
}
.content ul.venus-menu li a:hover {
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary " href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>
  <ul class="venus-menu" id="top_bar">
    <li><a href="#" title="首页" target="_blank">首页</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title1" target="_blank">title1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title2" target="_blank">title2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title3" target="_blank">title3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title4" target="_blank">title4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title5" target="_blank">title5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title6" target="_blank">title6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title7" target="_blank">title7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title8" target="_blank">title8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title9" target="_blank">title9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="title10" target="_blank">title10</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried change the relative css part as your suggestion, but   under my website seems no changes. I am not sure if it's caused by the Laravel frame constraint.

Comment: But fiddle is working as your requirement, and i think this is not a laravel issue.